# Trying to get n random numbers that don't end in 0 but still have n outputs. It's currently omitting all numbers that end in 0. What to do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I want to have for example 5 outputs of two random numbers (x and y) whilst not having any numbers that end in a zero.

The if statement omits all numbers that end in a zero, and since the numbers are random, I don't end up having exactly 5 outputs.

I want the program to either continue running until it has given me 10 outputs where none of the numbers end in a zero, or replace any number that it gets from the RNG that ends in a zero with another number that doesn't end in a zero.

```py
import random


for k in range(5):

    x = (random.randint(100, 1000))
    y = (random.randint(100, 1000))

    if (x % 10 != 0) and (y % 10 != 0):
            
        print(x, "+", y, "=")

    else:
            print("x")
```

E.g. as an Output:

'567 + 533 ='
'196 + 521 ='
'x'
'624 + 323 ='
'x'

Comment: Please post code/output as text, not images of text.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Keep a count of how many pairs you have printed, and stop the loop when you've printed enough.

Comment: generate a number between 10 and 99, multiply this number by 10, then add another random number between 1 and 9.

Comment: do you want to omit results where the sum of the two random numbers ends in 0 or do you want to ensure that neither of your two random numbers ends in 0?

Comment: Sorry for the images I've corrected it so the text is formatted into code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just generate random x, y in a while loop that can exit the loop only when both x and y doesn't end with zero

```
import random


for k in range(15):
    x, y = 10, 10
    while x % 10 == 0 or y % 10 == 0:
        x = random.randint(100, 1000)
        y = random.randint(100, 1000)

    print(x, "+", y, "=")
```

Alternatively, I think another way to work around this is to generate a list of numbers in range that doesn't end with zero and just randomly pick from it

```
import random

valid_nums = [x for x in range(100, 1001) if x % 10 != 0]
for k in range(15):
    x = random.choice(valid_nums)
    y = random.choice(valid_nums)

    print(x, "+", y, "=")
```

Comment: @jonSG I wanted each of x and y to not end in zero, just as the solution suggests. I must thank all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Why not write a function that builds a list of formatted strings then print the result in your main program? Something like this:

```
from random import randint

def getnums(n: int, r: tuple[int, int]=(100, 1000)) -> list[str]:
    rv = []
    while n > 0:
        if (x := randint(*r)) % 10 and (y := randint(*r)) % 10:
            rv.append(f'{x} + {y}=')
            n -= 1
    return rv

print(*getnums(5), sep='\n')
```

**Possible output:**

```
839 + 248=
154 + 106=
349 + 248=
881 + 425=
445 + 561=
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be to keep generating random numbers until 10 meet your needs.

```
import random


def _generate_non_zero_random_number():
    x = 0
    while x % 10 == 0:
        x = random.randint(100, 1000)

    return x

def _generate_2_random_numbers():
    return _generate_non_zero_random_number(),  _generate_non_zero_random_number()

for k in range(5):
    x, y = _generate_2_random_numbers()
    print(f"{x}+{y}=")
```

Alternatively, you could just add or subtract one from any random number that doesn't meet your criteria and the number will then meet the criteria.